401 response with Valid Bearer token using YARP
I am using YARP as an API Gateway to route requests to 2 backend services in .NET8. I followed the documentation to set it up and authorize the endpoints but I get a 401 even after getting a valid token from the auth service. Here's my setup:
YARP Setup (appsettings.json)
"ApiGateway": {
    "Routes": {
      "main-route": {
        "ClusterId": "mainCluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/main/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "AuthorizationPolicy": "Authenticated"
      },
      "auth-route": {
        "ClusterId": "authCluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/auth/{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "mainCluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "mainDestination": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5102/"
          }
        }
      },
      "authCluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "authDestination": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5101/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

JWT Setup on the API Gateway Service
public static IServiceCollection AddJwt(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var issuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_ISSUER") ??
                     throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find JWT ISSUER");
        var secret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_SECRET") ??
                     throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find JWT SECRET");

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = issuer,
                ValidAudience = issuer,
                SignatureValidator = (token, parameters) =>
                {
                    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
                    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
                    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

                    if (signingCredentials.Key is not SymmetricSecurityKey symmetricSecurityKey)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Signature validation failed.");
                    var encodedData = $"{jwt.EncodedHeader}.{jwt.EncodedPayload}";
                    var compiledSignature = Encode(encodedData, symmetricSecurityKey.Key);

                    if (compiledSignature == jwt.RawSignature)
                        return jwt;
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Signature validation failed.");
                },
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });

        return services;
    }

    private static string Encode(string encodedData, byte[] key)
    {
        HMACSHA256 myHmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedData);
        using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        byte[] hash = myHmacsha256.ComputeHash(ms);
        return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(hash);
    }

The Program.cs (APIGateway service)
var allowedSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(allowedSpecificOrigins, policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200",
                    "https://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApiGateway"));

builder.Services.AddJwt(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
    .AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(allowedSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapReverseProxy();

app.Run();

The JWT setup on the auth service is the same as above. And despite all this, I still get 401 when I try to call any of the Main endpoints via the Gateway even after obtaining a valid token and putting it in the header of the request.
I actually tried this with Ocelot first and moved to YARP when I had no success getting it to work and still no success. Someone point me to what I'm missing please. It's been 3 days since.
